# Play Framework 2.5 Form Field Validation

Tags: forms, validation, laravel, playframework

I am new to Play framework coming off from Laravel. I would like to know how to validate **Form** fields in Play similar to Laravel.

```
email => required|email|unique
```

And also create custom validation messages

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you haven't specified any details I am going to assume that you are using Java and Play 2.5

[There is built-in validation in Play which is described here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms#Defining-constraints)

Basically you define a class which represents that data of the form. For every field you can then specify different validations - in the form of annotations. For a list of available annotations and specifically the `Constraints.EmailValidator`, take a look [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/index.html?play/data/validation/Constraints.EmailValidator.html)

Of course you are free to provide more validation by overriding the `validate` method, by using `DynamicForm`s and handling the binding and validation yourself etc.

Comment: How can we do the same in Scala? I found that verifying method could be used to create new mappings. I noticed that there is a validate method as well but I couldn't find its use or definition in documentation. What is validate used for?